# Tiling a circle with convex figures of predefined location and size

Tags: geometry, combinatorial-geometry

I have been trying to prove Cauchy's integral formula "my way" and it didn't go well, but I found out another interesting geometry problem. If one could prove that my hypotheses are right, I would be able to finish my proof, which would be way more complicated than I initially thought.

The problem can be explained as maintaining a set of convex sets of euclidean plane that cover the given circle. Under "circle", I assume a closed circle defined by its center $c$ and radius $r$, the set: $D(c,r)=\{x\in\mathbb{E}^2\mid|x-c|\leqslant r\}$.

**The problem:**

Is there a positive real constant $K>1$ and a positive real constant $W>1$ such that for any given circle $B$ and any family of circles $\{A_i=D(c_i,r_i)\mid i\in I\}$ that:

1. cover the circle $B$: $\bigcup\{A_i\mid i\in I\}\supseteq B$ and
2. for every $i\in I$, $c_i\in B$,

there exists another family of sets $\{P_j\mid j\in J\}$ such that:

1. For every $j\in J$, the set $P_j$ is compact and convex,
2. For every two different indices $j_1,j_2\in J$ holds that $\emptyset=\text{int}P_{j_1}\cap\text{int}P_{j_2}$,
3. They are an exact cover of $B$: $\bigcup\{P_j\mid j\in J\}=B$,
4. For every $j\in J$ there exists $i\in I$ so that $c_i\in P_j\subseteq D(c_i,K\cdot r_i)$,

5. (**this is an extra property**) For every $j\in J$, the maximal width $M$ and the minimal width $m$ of $P_j$ form a ratio smaller than $W$: $\frac{M}{m}\leqslant W$?

The fifth condition is additional. If you can prove the theorem for only first four conditions, it is still good. The width of a figure $F$ here represents the minimal width of a strip (the closure of space between two parallel lines) of fixed direction that can completely cover the figure $F$. The minimal width and the maximal width here are taken as extremes when the direction is the parameter.

Comment: What are the cardinalities of these families? I ask because if J can be uncountable, then we can just take P_j to be a point in B, as points are compact and convex and have no interior. In addition if I can be countable, I believe we cannot satisfy condition 5, as there may be no minimum radius for the covering family of circles.

Comment: @IsaacBrowne You are right. Well, almost. Take a look at condition 4. Your first example doesn't satisfy the first half of condition 4 (a point from your collection might not be one of $c$'s). About second example, every closed circle $A$ you can cover with another **open** circle of $K$ times bigger radius. Now you'd have an open covering of a **compact** circle $B$. So you can assume that both families are finite.

Comment: @IsaacBrowne Sorry, you can actually assume that $I$ is finite. Then, it can be proven that if $I$ is finite, then $J$ has to be finite too. But I don't want to make it a condition because my idea for proving Cauchy's integral theorem would work even if these families are countably infinite.

Comment: If $I$ is finite and the $c_i$ are distinct, can you not just take the Voronoi partition of $B$ w.r.t. the $c_i$? This will satisfy the first four properties, but not the fifth in general.

Comment: @Servaes Acctually, you can't, sorry. Think about what happens when radii of circles A are drastically different. If you still don't see, I might add all counter-examples that I found in the question.

Comment: @Servaes But, I think I see a solution for the first four conditions thanks to you :)

Comment: @donaastor You're right. For some reason I only had circles of equal radius in mind. With some work I think the Voronoi partitions can be adjusted to satisfy the first four conditions. I look forward to seeing your solution, if you don't mind answering your own question :)

Comment: @Servaes Unfortunatelly, I still wasn't able to adjust Voronoi to work here. I will most probably edit the question soon to include all pathological examples that I've found.